# Can some one let me know why following Oozie coordinator is running in loop

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I was new to oozie process . I was testing the following coordinator.xml,when i submit the job it running in loop but I want to run everyday at 1:00 am .Can someone let me know what mistake i was doing.

```
<coordinator-app name="cron-coord-jon" frequency="0 1 * * *" start="2009-01-01T05:00Z" end="2036-01-01T06:00Z" timezone="UTC"
                 xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
        <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${workflowAppUri}</app-path>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>jobTracker</name>
                    <value>${jobTracker}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>nameNode</name>
                    <value>${nameNode}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>queueName</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinator is likely not running in a loop, but rather submitting every 'missed' job since the start date you specified. Set the start date to the current day (e.g. `2019-06-03T00:00Z`) and relaunch your coordinator.

If the start time is before 01:00, you should see a single job be launched for the day.

You may want to pass this in as a variable. Here is the call to `date` that will provide the current date & time in the correct format.

`date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ"`